# Difference between @section Scripts and the usual script tag used in ASP.Net WebForm

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the difference between the following 2 Javascripts?  I can use the second form of Javascript in Razor engine MVC pages without any issues, so what is the benefit of using the first form?

**MVC style**

```
@section Scripts {
    function check()
   {
      //do some validation logic here
   }
}
```

**WebForms style**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function check()
       {
          //do some validation logic here
       }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@section Scripts` doesn't produce any output in the page on its own, you need to render the section somewhere. When you use it, there is a `RenderSection` call somewhere, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@RenderSection('Scripts')
</script>
```

The fact that the section is named `Scripts` doesn't have any relevance, it's just a convention that is used for sections that contain scripts.

Comment: Why I can't simply use the normal script tags we had in Webforms ( the second code snippet in my question) if I don't care about putting the script in where RenderSection is defined then the second snippet should be fine.

Comment: @Sunil: You can very well use a regular script tag if you like. There is nothing that says that you need to use sections just because they exist.

Answer (score 1):

`@section Scripts {` is acting like place holder for your scripts. In your layout page you would include the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  ....
</head>
<body>
  // common html for all pages based on this layout
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

This is saying, that if the page includes the section `Scripts`, then render it here. So your page that uses this layout might have the following

```
@section scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  <script src="../../Scripts/YourScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#SomeElement').click(function() {
      // do something
    });
  </script>
}
```

and `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` would be replaced by whats in the `@section scripts {`

Answer (score 1):

This may work, but won't be ideal for one reason:

```
@section Scripts {
    function check()
   {
      //do some validation logic here
   }
}
```

Will cause you to lose intellisense. It  may work, but will make life more difficult. It's often best to include the script tag:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function check()
   {
      //do some validation logic here
   }
   </script>
}
```

Also @section scripts renders where a @RenderSection("Scripts") is defined in the master page.  Without it, it renders EXACTLY where the script tag you have (in your WebForms example).

Comment: So if I used the second form then script would render where its exactly defined and not in master page. If yes, then its better to not include some scripts in master page especially if the they ajax requests to that particular MVC View.